# has_many through multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two main models: Product and Service. You can create an Issue corresponding to a particular Product or Service.

The user responds to an Issue by creating a Ticket corresponding to the Issue. Alternatively, the user can create a Ticket directly from a Product or Service.

When a Ticket is created, a list of any previous (unresponded) Issues corresponding to the Product or Service that the Ticket belongs to is displayed, and these can be added to the Ticket. New Issues can also be created and added to the Ticket.

I'd like to combine the two arrays unresponded_product_issues and unresponded_service_issues into one array. How can I combine the two throughs (i.e through :product and :service)?

I'm using Rails 3 (3.2).

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets
  has_many :issues
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
  has_many :tickets
end

class Issue  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :service
end

class Ticket  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :issues
  has_many :unresponded_product_issues, :through=>:product, :source=>:issues, :conditions=>{:ticket_id=>nil}
  has_many :unresponded_service_issues, :through=>:service, :source=>:issues, :conditions=>{:ticket_id=>nil} 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unresponded_product_issues
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :unresponded_service_issues
end
```

Update: In response to @SteveTurczyn's comment below, I have tried declaring a method as follows:

```
def unresponded_issues
    unresponded_product_issues + unresponded_service_issues
end
```

I have a form (below) in my erb template, and the issue I'm running into here is the error below:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass):
<%= form_for [@ticket] do |f| %>
28:             <%= f.fields_for :unresponded_issues do |issue| %>
29:             <tr>
30:                 <td><%= issue.check_box :responded,
31:                     :id => "#{@ticket.id}-#{issue.object.id}" %></td>
```

Note that I get the same error if iterate over `unresponded_product_issues` or `unresponded_service_issues` and the error only goes away if I add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :unresponded_product_issues` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :unresponded_service_issues` to the Ticket model.

I attempted to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :unresponded_issues` which resulted in an error `No association found for name 'unresponded_issues'`.

Comment: I think you should be able to do ... `class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base; ... ; def unresponded_issues; unresponded_product_issues + unresponded_service_issues; end ; end `

Comment: Thanks for the response. That didn't work (I get an error in a form in my erb template) - see my update above.

Comment: I fixed the issue in my form by doing `<%= form_for [@ticket], do |f| %> <% @ticket.unresponded_issues.each do |issue| %>
   <%= f.simple_fields_for i do |issue_form| %>`. Thanks  @SteveTurczyn for the help.

Comment: Hi, glad it worked! Cheers - Steve

Comment: @SteveTurczyn do create an answer for that line. it's good for google fodder and your street cred.